# Give a client working PHP file that is executable in Windows that also outputs directories and files

Tags: php, windows, csv, file

I created a PHP script that takes an input of a CSV file through the web browser and outputs a bunch of directories and files according to the CSV file. Now I want to give this to my client as a standalone application without the need to host their own LAMP stack as my client is not technical at all. He just wants it to live natively on their desktop where he can easily click to open it.

Comment: PHP would need to be installed on the client's system with the desired modules (gd, etc) and given appropriate permissions that can be run from a batch file. I would recommend converting it to a Windows batch or PowerShell script file. Depends on what all the PHP script is doing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Docker.
You can make the php script run from docker by creating a folder structure like this:

- docker-compose.yml # This file should contain the docker configurations
- run-application.bat # This file should run the docker application
- app/ # Insert the script and map it inside the docker configuration

once run-application.bat is clicked the script should run docker and create a LAMP server mapped to the client computer local port.
You can also decide to automaticaly open the browser.

Comment: any examples of this done? i've never used docker before.

Comment: Some time ago i made a docker configuration from scratches, but i don't know if is still working: https://github.com/boghy933/web-dev-docker-env (I don't remember how to start the project i think with with `docker-compose up`)

Comment: You need to do something similar, but you have to add a bash file that the client should click to run the docker application

Answer (score 0):

Two steps only, 5 minutes. Put EasyPHP (https://www.easyphp.org) on a USB key and put your file in "www". Your client will able to run those file by launching EasyPHP. He can even copy the whole folder on his hard drive. EasyPHP is portable.